# display a table from a excel sheet

Tags: javascript, html, excel, export, html-table

I want to display a table from a excel sheet in my html page. There are multiple tables in a excel sheet. I want a specific table to be displayed. Please Help..

The HTML code i used to extract information from excel file

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>
 From Excel
 </title>
 <script language="javascript" >
 function GetData(cell,row){
 var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
 var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\abc.xlsx");
 var excel_sheet = excel.Worksheets("25 PEs");
 var data = excel_sheet.Cells(cell,row).Value;
 document.getElementById('div1').innerText =data;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="div1" style="background: #DFDFFF; width:'100%';" align="center">
Click buttons to fetch data from c:\abc.xlsx
</div>

<input name="Button1" type="button" onClick="GetData(1,1)" value="button1">
<input name="Button2" type="button" onClick="GetData(1,2)" value="button2">
<input name="Button3" type="button" onClick="GetData(2,1)" value="button3">
<input name="Button4" type="button" onClick="GetData(2,2)" value="button4">


</body>
</html>
```

This code extracts one cell at a time. I want to extract an entire table at once.
How to do it?

Comment: any limitation? what language you prefer?

Comment: Do you understand that this code works only if Excel file are placed on client machine ?

Answer (score 4):

A good option is to use the jquery library dataTables. You can then use a tool such as that provided by Mr DataConverter to convert your spreadsheet into json. You then point your datatables to the json file, filter out any columns you dont need, and viola, your data is displayed in a nice html table, and customised to how you like it. I have used this approach just recently and it has made displaying a huge amount of data that much easier.

DataTables - http://www.datatables.net/

Mr Data Converter - http://www.shancarter.com/data_converter/index.html

The code to hide individual columns would look something like this in your dataTables intializer:

```
"aoColumnDefs" : [{
    "bVisible" : false,
    "bSearchable": true, 
    "aTargets" : [0, 1, 4, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12]
}
```

and to re-order the columns would look something like:

```
"aoColumns": [//reorder the columns
    { "mDataProp": [0] },
    { "mDataProp": [1] },
    { "mDataProp": [2] },
    { "mDataProp": [7] },
    { "mDataProp": [4] },
],
```

hope this is of some help...

Comment: this works fine...I am doing the same for one of my projects...works totally fine if you do not have formula and all